# Forming 4-digit odd numbers under certain rules

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many four-digit odd numbers can be formed such that every $"3"$ in the number is followed by a $"6"$?

- A) 108
- B) 2592
- C) 2696
- D) 2700

A "3" need not be *immediately* followed by a "6", and each "3" must be uniquely associated with a "6", i.e. multiple occurrences of a "3" cannot share the same "6".

Comment: Does the three have to be immediately followed by a six? So is $3161$ acceptable? Or does it have to be more like $1361$?

Comment: we have to infer it from the question and take all possibilities

Comment: You should clarify with your professor, because the answers will be different based on the two cases.

Comment: it was from a competitive exam. anyways, I have solved with both cases at a time and it matches the answer the book says. could you look at it and see if it looks okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: firstly take a look at the possibilities without $"3"$: you have $8$ choices for the *1st* digit, $9$ choices for the *2nd* digit, $9$ choices for the *3rd* digit, and finally $4$ choices for the last digit (in order to be odd, the number must end with $1,3,5,7 \text{ or } 9$) $\Rightarrow$ at least $8\cdot 9\cdot 9\cdot 4 = 2592$ numbers, so answers *A* and *B* can't be right...then try by examinate the number of numbers with only *1* $"3"$, *2* $"3"$, and so on...

Comment: will notify soon

Answer (score 0):

total no. of digits without 3 is 2592. 
let us assume the number is "x x x y". where y is an odd digit but not 3, since every 3 has to be followed by a 6. hence y can be 1,5,7,9.  also, 3 cannot fill into the third x because if it does so, then 6 cannot follow it. now there are three cases.

case 1:

3 6 x y

there are 4 possibilities for y and 9 for x.
so it can be done in 9*4= 36 ways.

case 2:

x 3 6 y

here too, y can take 4 forms and x can take anything but 0 and 3, hence 8 forms.

there are 4*8= 32 possibilities

case 3:

3 x 6 y

y can take 4 forms and x can take 9 (0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9) forms

number of ways of filling it up is 4*9= 36 possibilities.

adding the number of numbers without 3 with those that have three, we get, 2592+36+36+32= 2696, which is the answer.

Answer (score -1):

consider ABCD , A{1..9} , B{0..9}, C{0..9} D{1,5,7,9}
P{odd}=9*10*10*4=3600
subtract P{A=3 and B not =6 }
subtract P{B=3 and C not = 6}
subtract P{c=3 }
add P{A=3,B=6,c not =3}
Answer=3600-1*9*10*4 -....... + ....=2592

Comment: total number of odd digits without 3 is 2592, hence, I think, the answer cannot be it. it has to be 2696 or 2700

Comment: Total number of odd digits without 3 is 3600 (9x10x10x4=3600)

Comment: you have to exclude "0" from the thousands place